# Ethernet Not Visible In Settings

Tags: ipad, ethernet

On my *iPad 2017* (5th Generation) the *Ethernet* section in Settings (see image below) is not displayed.

Do I have to unlock it somehow (similar to Developer Tools on Android) or is this feature simply not available for my hardware?

[image]

Comment: From where is this screenshot?

Comment: 5th Gen iPads do not have a USB-C port, only Lightning. Did you rig up a Frankenstein cable and adapter chain to plug this iPad in to Ethernet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be implied from the title of the right-hand side, this feature requires a [Belkin USB-C LAN Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJKF2ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter) to work, and currently either an 11-inch or a 3rd gen 12.9-inch iPad Pro.